# Method with nested generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have something along the lines:

```
public class BaseClass
{

}

public class SimpleDerivedA : BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething() => Expression.Empty();        
}

public class SimpleDerivedB : BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething() => Expression.Empty();          
}

public class GenericDerived<T> : BaseClass where T : struct
{
    public T data;
    public void DoSomething<T>(T someParameter) => Expression.Empty();        
}

public void Process<T, X>(T someObject, X someValue = default) where T : BaseClass where X : struct
{
    switch (someObject)
    {
        case SimpleDerivedA a:
            a.DoSomething();
            break;
        case SimpleDerivedB b:
            b.DoSomething();
            break;
        case GenericDerived<X> g:
            X obj = new X();
            g.DoSomething(obj);
            break;
    }

}
```

Process method works in an ugly way:

```
    SimpleDerivedA a = new SimpleDerivedA();
    SimpleDerivedB b = new SimpleDerivedB();
    GenericDerived<Vector3> g = new GenericDerived<Vector3>();

    Process(a, new int()); //second parameter is fake, just to be able to 
    call the method
    Process(b, new int()); //second parameter is fake, just to be able to 
    call the method
    Process(g, new Vector3());//second parameter is fake, just to be able to 
    call the method
```

Ideally I should be able to call Process(a), Process(b), Process(g)

Something like:

```
public void Process<T>(T someObject)  where T: BaseClass where X: struct
    {
        switch (someObject)
        {
            case SimpleDerivedA a:
                a.DoSomething();
                break;
            case SimpleDerivedB b:
                b.DoSomething();
                break;
            case GenericDerived<X> g:
                var obj = new X();
                g.DoSomething(obj);
                break;
        }

    }
```

or:

```
public void Process<T<X>>(T someObject) where T : BaseClass where X : struct
    {
        switch (someObject)
        {
            case SimpleDerivedA a:
                a.DoSomething();
                break;
            case SimpleDerivedB b:
                b.DoSomething();
                break;
            case GenericDerived<X> g:
                var obj = new X();
                g.DoSomething(obj);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Which obviously don't compile. I need to use it inside an API and the type of `GenericDerived<T>` won't be known until someone will use it.

The question here is how can I define the method Process so I can use an instance of any of the three derived classes as a parameter but call it only with one parameter like `Process(value)` not `Process(value, fakeValue)` or `Process<SomeType>(value)`?

Comment: How about using interface instead?

Comment: @ just-my-name what should I derive from interface? All classes?

Comment: I posted it as an answer since it was kind of long for a comment.

Comment: You should change the name of `T` for `DoSomething` in `GenericDerived` to avoid hiding the outer type parameter (or remove it in case it should be the outer one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an overload of your `Process` function for objects of type `GenericDerived`, instead of trying to handle everything in one function.

```
void Process<T>(T someObject) where T : BaseClass {
    switch (someObject)
    {
        case SimpleDerivedA a:
            a.DoSomething();
            break;
        case SimpleDerivedB b:
            b.DoSomething();
            break;
    }
}

void Process<X>(GenericDerived<X> g) where X : struct {
    X obj = new X();
    g.DoSomething(obj);
}
```

You can then call it like this.

```
var a = new SimpleDerivedA();
var b = new SimpleDerivedB();
var g = new GenericDerived<Vector3>();

Process(a);
Process(b);
Process(g);
```

Also consider introducing an interface for objects that can `DoSomething`, or add a virtual method to `BaseClass`, so you don't have to type-switch just to call the same method on different objects. This might not be possible since there's a parameter in some derived classes but not others.

Comment: Very good idea, overloading the method is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add interface to the base class.

```
interface IProcessable
{
    void DoSomething(params object [] args);
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IProcessable
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(params object[] args);
}

public class GenericDerived<T> : BaseClass where T : struct
{
    public T data;
    public override void DoSomething(params object[] args)
    {
        // optionally you can pass as many arguments as you like
        data = (T)args.First();
    }
}
```

And then you can pass your object into method like this.

```
public static void Process(IProcessable obj, params object[] args)
{
    obj.DoSomething(args);
}
```

Then call it from where ever you need like this

```
var a =  new SimpleDerivedA();
var b = new SimpleDerivedB();
var c = new GenericDerived<T>();
Process(a);
Process(b);
Process(c, obj /* your struct T */);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IGenericDoSomething
{
  void DoSomethingWithDefault();
}

public class GenericDerived<T> : BaseClass, IGenericDoSomething where T : struct
{
  public T data;
  public void DoSomething<X>(X someParameter) => Console.WriteLine(someParameter);

  void IGenericDoSomething.DoSomethingWithDefault() => DoSomething(default(T)); 
}

  public void Process<T>(T someObject) where T : BaseClass {
    switch (someObject)
    {
      case SimpleDerivedA a:
        a.DoSomething();
        break;
      case SimpleDerivedB b:
        b.DoSomething();
        break;
      case IGenericDoSomething g:
        g.DoSomethingWithDefault();
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need to pass a parameter to `DoSomething<X>(X someParameter)` inside `Process() ` method not inside `GenericDerived` class.

Comment: In this case you need to know a type of the this parameter in a Process method. Do you know this? Can you show an example?